# Cardano-Node Preview Testnet PeerSelection Error

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

I am running cardano-node 1.35.3 on Ubuntu 22.04 Docker container. I am attempting to run the node on the preview testnet. Below is the following error I get when running cardano-node.

Here is the Error that I am seeing

```
[22cbd0dd:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Error:52] [2022-09-29 04:11:19.93 UTC] TracePublicRootsFailure Network.Socket.getAddrInfo (called with preferred socket type/protocol: AddrInfo {addrFlags = [AI_ADDRCONFIG,AI_NUMERICHOST,AI_PASSIVE], addrFamily = AF_UNSPEC, addrSocketType = Datagram, addrProtocol = 0, addrAddress = 0.0.0.0:0, addrCanonName = Nothing}, host name: Just "192.168.65.5", service name: Just "domain"): does not exist (Unrecognized service) (-5) 32s
[22cbd0dd:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:52] [2022-09-29 04:11:51.89 UTC] TraceGovernorWakeup
[22cbd0dd:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:52] [2022-09-29 04:11:51.89 UTC] TracePublicRootsRequest 100 0
[22cbd0dd:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-09-29 04:11:51.89 UTC] [String "FetchingNewLedgerState",Number 0.0]
[22cbd0dd:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-09-29 04:11:51.89 UTC] [String "FallingBackToBootstrapPeers"]
[22cbd0dd:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-09-29 04:11:51.89 UTC] [String "UseLedgerAfter",Number 322000.0]
[22cbd0dd:cardano.node.PublicRootPeers:Info:66] [2022-09-29 04:11:51.89 UTC] TracePublicRootRelayAccessPoint [RelayAccessDomain "preview-node.world.dev.cardano.org" 30002]
```

Here is my cardano-node run command
`cardano-node run --topology topology.json --database-path db --socket-path db/node.socket --host-addr 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --config config.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the testnet does not work for cardano-node 1.35.3. I have to run cardano-node 1.35.2 to use the testnet

Answer (score 1):

`apt install netbase` in your container. it worked out for me.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm running cardano-node in a base debian container image.

Answer (score 0):

These logs look like an issue with you config.jason file in your public root section you are calling a service name that it can not find. Would need to see your config.jason file to comment more

Comment: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preview/config.json

Comment: Sorry not config.json, topology.json. the config.json is fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Have a look at the following answer, changing the host-addr worked in my case:

https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/9203/7074